# Recognising a redirect to exception page as an error in JMeter

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

I'm testing an ASP.NET application using JMeter. Occasionally there will be an exception caused somewhere, and the page will redirect to an screen displaying the exception message.

How can I get JMeter to recognise this as a error? At the moment its showing as a green indicator, since I'm successfully getting a response.

[image: redirect to exception page]

I want to be able to recognise this as an error so it shows later on in the reporting/aggregation listeners.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an assertion as a child to the request which can check the contents of the reply and raise an error if needed.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion